# Hibernate second level cache (TreeCache) - For sub entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss-cache

I am using TreeCache as my hibernate second level entity cache. I have an entity hierarchy which contains Customers and Partners both extend from Users. Can I cache Partner only ? I can cache Users then both customers and parers getting cached as well. But I want to cache a selected sub type. I am using a single table per class hierarchy strategy to store data .(single table with discriminator column). Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Regards,

Era

Comment: What happens if you try doing it?

Comment: In hibernate mapping <cache> can not specify under <subclass> element. If I do so I am getting a runtime error saying "Could not parse mapping document from invalid mapping". But <cache> can specify under <class> element.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure but you may have issues with chosen inheritance strategy, see:
- http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/4849.page
- http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/15/4849.page
- https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=937742

Regards
Philippe

Comment: It seems can not cache the sub entities without root entity. Caching need to initiate from the root entity. Can you suggest me a way to support sub type caching ? Any possible code hacking ?